# How can I use the delete button of muidatatable?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

Whenever I'll click a row, it'll show a delete button. How can I access that button and put my own delete codes there?

Answer (score 1):

use like this :

```
const options = {
    onRowsDelete:(e)=>{console.log(e.data)}, <---- e.data is a array of rows
    selectableRows:'single',
}

render(){
return(
<MUIDataTable
        title={"title"}
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        options={options}
      />
)
}
```

Comment: with `e.data` I'm not able to see the data : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rEa1iMm2HjjGIa39Aprghtem5dHqxMR1/view?usp=sharing         e.data[0]:  
{index: 0, dataIndex: 0}
dataIndex: 0
index: 0
__proto__: Object.   e.data[0].title:  undefined

Comment: use console.log(e) and show me what you see

Comment: with console.log(e) when clicking the trash icon I see this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fbLCMqCeywuMEfuB9symtTUpcEqaY1W7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's ok, and you can get deleted row info (index 0) and you can delete from your array

Comment: there are two indexes :  `{index: 0, dataIndex: 0}` and it's not clear to me how these two indexes relate to a redux store. What  `index` and `dataIndex` mean in practical terms?

Comment: I've put a question in the mui-datatables github's repo : https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/issues/1689 . May be you can answer then